# binding dropdownList only shows 1 letter on each line

Tags: c#, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

so i have a strange issue with my dropdown where it only will show the first letter of the printername and then makes a line break with the second letter and so on [image]

action result

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Settings(SettingsModel setting)
        {
            List<SettingsModel> settings = new List<SettingsModel>();
            foreach (string name in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            {

                //Load the XML file in XmlDocument.
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XML/Settings.xml"));
                //Loop through the selected Nodes.

                foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/Settings/UserSettings"))
            {
                    //Fetch the Node values and assign it to Model.
                    settings.Add(new SettingsModel
                    {
                    Printername = name,
                    AutoCreateSoldPart = node["AutoCreateSoldPart"].InnerText,
                    });

                }
            }
            return View(settings);
        }
```

view

```
@using ActionLink_Send_Model_MVC.Models
@model IEnumerable<SettingsModel>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Settings", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        foreach (SettingsModel setting in Model)
        {
                    <td class="auto-style7">Printer: </td>
                    <td class="auto-style8">
                        @Html.DropDownList("SettingsModel", new SelectList(setting.Printername))                   
                    </td>
```

Comment: You are using the Printername as a new select list. This is splitting the letters up into selectable items!

Comment: how do i then get the whole string for each printers as a item?

Comment: You code makes no sense. Your binding to a property named `SettingsModel` which does not exist. And then you use a `string` for the options - the 2nd parameter needs to be `new SelectList(yourCollectionOfPrinterNames)`

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen - I've posted an answer that should help.

Answer (score 0):

in your view model you need a list of SelectListItem as the source of your combo content. You will then also need a property to bind to which represents the selected item from the combo.

Something like the below.

```
public class PrintSettingsModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> PrintSettings { get; set; }
    public string PrinterSelected { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, you populate the model with a new list.

Again, along the lines of the below. Ideally you should have a service that returns you a list of SelectListItem that you assign to your model.

```
public ActionResult ShowPrinters()
{
    var printerModel = new PrintSettingsModel();
    printerModel.PrintSettings = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "Printer1",   //Your printer details from XML
            Value = "Printer1"
         }
     };

        return View("ShowPrinter", printerModel);
}
```

Then in your view, use the helper. This specifies "PrinterSelected" to bind to and uses the model for the combo options.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PrinterSelected, new List<SelectListItem>(Model.PrintSettings), "-- Please Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I've just tried this locally and it seems ok.

Finally, assuming you are going to perform a post with a selected printer setting. The model should contain "PrinterSelected". You then use this value to retrieve any more info you need from a known list of printers, i.e. the same list you used to populate the model.

Hope that helps.